# OpenLayers: select feature from info passed in URL?

Tags: openlayers

I've been thrown in at the deep end with virtually no knowledge of js or OpenLayers and a mapping project which needs to be done yesterday. I am quite comfortable with things like OOP and unit testing in other languages.

I have a "jigsaw"-type map divided up into lots of bounded areas (properties). When you click on one, the boundary is highlighted.

There is also a normal html page with further info on each property.

I need to create a link to the map page and have the property boundary automatically highlighted without the user having to click on it first. I can pass some info in the url easily enough but I haven't got much of a clue what to do next. Do I need to find an object of type OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature and then call the select method?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We have "areas" made up of "unit" polygons.  Our users can select a unit from a menu and that unit will highlight on the map.  This sounds like what you are trying to do.

The way we did it is that we have one layer that displays all the unit polygons in an area.  Each polygon in the "all" layer has a different colour with no border.  If the user selects a specific unit then we retrieve a second layer by passing a where clause to the server so only that one unit's polygon is retrieved.  The "unit" layer is the same polygon fill colour but with a dark border.  The "unit" layer is overlayed on top of the "all" layer by OpenLayers.

To the user, it looks like the "unit" is highlighted - the fill is darker from 2 layers and that unit has a border while the other units have no border.  Another reason we did it this way is so the user could choose to have the "all" layer on or off - it sits on top of a base map layer.

It sounds like you could have an "outline" layer that just has the border of one of your polygons.  This "outline" layer would overlay on top of your base layer and would look like you were highlighting the boundary of one of your properties.

I know this doesn't answer your question on how to do the approach you're considering, but it gives you an alternative approach that works well in some cases.